# How to add in-app airplay control on OS X

Tags: macos, airplay

I would like to add airplay control in my application on OS X and play a video on Apple TV, without using the airplay mirroring feature. The behaviour should be similar to the video player on iOS. On iOS, you can do this via the "MPVolumeView", which supplies an airplay button and let you control the route. Is there a "MPVolumeView" equivalance on OS X? if not, how can I add in-app airplay control in my application on OS X?

Comment: Why do I get a negative vote?